# detect if pattern exist Photoshop scripting

Tags: javascript, jsx, extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to detect if a pattern name exist on Photoshop but right now I'm not able to do it, anyone have any clue of how to do it?
Right now I have this:

```
function selectPattern(ptrn) {
  var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
  var ref = new ActionReference();
  ref.putName(charIDToTypeID('Ptrn'), ptrn );
  desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), ref );
  executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "slct" ), desc, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

but every time I use it the pattern name can't be found, it's used something like this:

```
selectPattern('Gauze');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's the same script as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094460/how-check-if-photoshop-brush-exist-programmatically) question. You can get the list of different presets from `Application` action reference:

```js
var patternsNames = getPresetList(4);

function getPresetList(presetIndex)
{
  // presetIndex: 0 to 7
  // 0: Brushes
  // 1: Swatches
  // 2: Gradients
  // 3: Styles
  // 4: Patterns
  // 5: Contours
  // 6: Custom Shapes
  // 7: Tools

  var presetNames = [];
  var ref = new ActionReference();
  ref.putProperty(stringIDToTypeID("property"), stringIDToTypeID("presetManager"));
  ref.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("application"), stringIDToTypeID("ordinal"), stringIDToTypeID("targetEnum"));
  var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
  var list = desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("presetManager"));
  var nameList = list.getObjectValue(presetIndex).getList(stringIDToTypeID("name"));
  for (var nameIndex = 0; nameIndex < nameList.count; nameIndex++)
  {
    var n = nameList.getString(nameIndex);
    presetNames.push(n);
  }
  return presetNames;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this doesn't directly answer your question it may be useful to you:

You can find out a pattern's ID with the scriptListener.

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

fillWithPattern("456e6678-5dd6-5046-9e0c-12871fb51bb0");

function fillWithPattern (patternid)
{
// =======================================================
var idFl = charIDToTypeID( "Fl  " );
var desc126 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idFrom = charIDToTypeID( "From" );
var desc127 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc127.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 100.0 ); // x fill point
var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc127.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, 100.0 ); //y fill point
var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );
desc126.putObject( idFrom, idPnt, desc127 );
var idTlrn = charIDToTypeID( "Tlrn" );
desc126.putInteger( idTlrn, 0 );
var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
var idFlCn = charIDToTypeID( "FlCn" );
var idPtrn = charIDToTypeID( "Ptrn" );
desc126.putEnumerated( idUsng, idFlCn, idPtrn );
var idPtrn = charIDToTypeID( "Ptrn" );
var desc128 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
desc128.putString( idNm, "" ); // pattern name (ignored)
var idIdnt = charIDToTypeID( "Idnt" );
desc128.putString( idIdnt, patternid ); //pattern ID
var idPtrn = charIDToTypeID( "Ptrn" );
desc126.putObject( idPtrn, idPtrn, desc128 );
executeAction( idFl, desc126, DialogModes.NO );
}
```